# Obtener valores de un consultar sql stringbuilder en c#

Tags: c#, querystring

Como podria obtener los datos que me arroja esa consulta y mantenerlos en una variable

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sqlidos = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                sqlidos.Append("select td.id_traslado,td.id_traslado_detalle,td.id_articulo,ar.nombre,ar.modelo,ar.referencia,ar.codigo1,ar.codigo2 from traslado_detalle td ");
                sqlidos.Append("inner join articulo ar on ar.articuloid = td.id_articulo  ");
                sqlidos.Append("where td.id_traslado_detalle = @p0 ");
```

lo he intentado de las dos siguientes formas pero no logro conseguirlo

forma 1:

```
var registros = db.Database.SqlQuery<Traslados>(sqlidos.ToString()).ToList();
```

forma 2:

```
var registros = db.Database.SqlQuery(sqlidos.ToString(),new SqlParameter("@p0", 1)).ToList();
```

en la segunda forma genera error que tiene argumentos no validos

```
Error   1   La mejor coincidencia de método sobrecargado para 'System.Data.Entity.Database.SqlQuery(System.Type, string, params object[])' tiene algunos argumentos no válidos
```

Comment: estoy intentando hacerlo de cualquier forma diferente de linq

Comment: genera un error que dice que tiene argumentos no validos

Comment: Como te he dicho, pulsa en [edit] y copia y pega exactamente el código del error ahi

Comment: de esta forma el error desaparece  pero no obtengo lo que quiero

Comment: Cual es el problema? la forma 1 no funciona? que es db.Database.SqlQuery?

Comment: Sospecho (pero como no uso Entity Framework nunca, no puedo asegurarlo) que el problema es que intentas mapear tu consulta a `Traslados`, pero tu consulta lo que devuelven son campos diferentes de un join. Probablemente, necesites crear una clase con las mismas propiedades que campos devuelve tu query, para mapear tu consulta a ello. Como digo, no uso Entity Framework nunca, asi que a ver si alguien con mas experiencia te lo aclara

Comment: Igual el problema que ahora si veo, mas alla de los anteriores, es que nunca pasa el parametro al query...

Comment: por que lo dices? ahi esta la instruccion `where td.id_traslado_detalle = @p0`

Comment: Concuerdo con @gbianchi,al parecer nunca pasa el parametro. @Andrex_11 por que no pruebas el query de forma plana, sin pasar ningun parametro, coloca de forma quemada o directa el `td.id_traslado_detalle` con un id existente, si te funciona, entoces el query esta correcto, el mapeo a la clase esta correcto, y el error seria como se pasa el parametro @p0.

Comment: Escribiste que tu query recibe un parametro, pero para pasarselo, deberias incluirlo en la llamada. La forma2 no es correcta, porque no existe ese metodo. No se que metodos tenes para pasarle el parametro, pero una cosa es definirlo en el query, y otra pasarle el valor.

Comment: gracias por responder, a la final decidí hacerlo por linq para no quemar tiempo en el asunto y funciona sin ningún inconveniente

Comment: @Andrex_11 no te desanimes. La pregunta es interesante, probablemente alguien sea capaz de darte una respuesta exacta :)

Comment: Gracias @pikoh, intentare darle solución

Comment: vuelvo a repetir mi comentario anterior. si supieramos de que tipo son db.Database.SqlQuery podriamos saber de que clases hablas y darle una solucion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu forma1: Falta pasarle el parametro.

```
var registros = db.Database.SqlQuery<Traslados>(sqlidos.ToString(),new SqlParameter("@p0", 1)).ToList();
```

En tu forma2: Como no utilizaste el Metodo generico `SqlQuery<TSource>`, entonces debiste pasarle el tipo de datos a mapear al metodo como primer argumento.

```
var registros = db.Database.SqlQuery(typeof(Traslados), sqlidos.ToString(),new SqlParameter("@p0", 1)).ToList();
```

Basandome de que tu clase `Traslados` tienes las propiedades para ser mapeadas te coloco este codigo para que pruebes:

```
string query = @"
    select
        td.id_traslado,
        td.id_traslado_detalle,
        td.id_articulo,
        ar.nombre,
        ar.modelo,
        ar.referencia,
        ar.codigo1,
        ar.codigo2
    from
        traslado_detalle td
    inner
        join articulo ar on ar.articuloid = td.id_articulo
    where
        td.id_traslado_detalle = @p0
    ";

List<Traslados> registros1 = db.Database.SqlQuery<Traslados>(query, SqlParameter("@p0", 1)).ToList();

List<Traslados> registros2 = db.Database.SqlQuery(typeof(Traslados), query, SqlParameter("@p0", 1)).ToList();
```